# How to properly ask for help on a complicated Question?

Tags: discussion, questions

I am looking for help on a calculation of mine that is related to Black Hole Quasinormal Mode undergraduate research I am doing with my university. This is not homework or anything, but I'd rather not bother my professor with this question, because as it stands I probably bother him with the number of questions I already ask, and I want to keep most of our conversations productive. But I digress.

The question is kind of tough, and niche, and I am not sure how much I am expected to show from my work when posing the question to Physics SE. I have much of it written out, but it’s getting to be a bit of a wall of text and equations.

What is the proper way to ask for assistance in a situation like this?

Comment: If you are planning to ask about a specific calculation, you should read the FAQ and the meta site regarding how to ask a homework question (see: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/). Even though your question is allegedly "not homework or anything" it is still likely *homework-like* if it is a specific niche calculation. The problem with these kinds of questions is that they are often not helpful to any other user of the site beside the asker and those types of questions are discouraged here.

Comment: @hft would it be more helpful to ask about the general technique then? There is really not much material out there on this topic that is pointed towards undergraduates, and PhysSE is one of the few places ive seen questions get answered

Comment: Probably, yes. But I'm just commenting since I'm not sure what the best answer is. Maybe some mods or other more high powered users will weigh in on what they think is best.

Comment: *I want to keep most of our conversations productive.* I don't understand this. If the professor is your advisor, wouldn't any discussion you have that helps you with the research be productive? You can almost surely pare down what you've written for this site and send a quick email to them, right? (e.g., "I was doing X and got stuck, are there any books/papers/tips you could give for help?")

Comment: That is what I ultimately ended up doing. Maybe its just general insecurities about school, and being a 'non-traditional' student, but I find myself worrying that I am too frequently asking questions and  eating up faculty resources lol.

Comment: Faculty resources are there to answer questions of their advisees...